# I found the chromoting viewer in my chromium addons is that supposed to be there on a default install?

Tags: security, chromium

So I found chromoting viewer in my add-ons for chromium. Is that supposed to be there? I just installed chromium and only installed the pepper flash player.

I disabled chromium and got an error is crashed but it didn't and then a popup that said the default file was modified asking me if I want to include it in the error report.

The default file:

> ## Default settings for chromium-browser. This file is sourced by /bin/sh from
>
> ## /usr/bin/chromium-browser
>
> ## Options to pass to chromium-browser
>
> CHROMIUM_FLAGS=""
>
> ## part for pepperflashplugin-nonfree : begin
>
> flashso="/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/libpepflashplayer.so"
>
> if [ -f $flashso ]
>
> then
>
> ```
>    flashversion=`strings $flashso|grep ^LNX|sed -e "s/^LNX //"|sed -e "s/,/./g"`
>
>    CHROMIUM_FLAGS="$CHROMIUM_FLAGS --ppapi-flash-path=$flashso --ppapi-flash->version=$flashversion"
> ```
>
> fi

>

> ## part for pepperflashplugin-nonfree : end

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is supposed to be there. Expanding the Details shows that it's meant to be used to access other computers that have been shared with you. Note that to use this, you need to first install the Chrome Remote Desktop app.